# the application crash when open it with admob-android

Tags: android, admob

This is the activity where I added the ad:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

/*  Intent intent = new Intent(this, SelectArticle.class);
    startActivity(intent);*/

    // Create the adView
   adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a15172dfcf0c366");

    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    TableLayoutlayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

At the end of the manifest :

```
      <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I also add the jar file googleAdmob.

When I open the app it's crash. What should I add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your app is crashing is because you are calling `findViewById()` before you call `setContentView()`. To fix this, move the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` to just below the `super.onCreate()` line.
That will still not solve your problem, because when you call findViewById, you are using R.layout.main_activity, which will not work because it is a layout. You have to give the `linearlayout` in your XML file the attribute `android:id="@+id/main_activity` and then you have to change the line where you instantiate your linear layout to

findViewById(R.**id**.activity_main)